# Get all rows from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have been trying to get all rows from the SQLite database. But I got only last row from the following codes.

**FileChooser class:**

```
public ArrayList<String> readFileFromSQLite() {

  fileName = new ArrayList<String>();

  fileSQLiteAdapter = new FileSQLiteAdapter(FileChooser.this);
  fileSQLiteAdapter.openToRead();
  cursor = fileSQLiteAdapter.queueAll();

  if (cursor != null) {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      do {
        fileName.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FileSQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT1)));
      } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    cursor.close();
  }

  fileSQLiteAdapter.close();
  return fileName;
}
```

**FileSQLiteAdapter class:**

```
public Cursor queueAll() {
  String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_CONTENT1 };

  Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns, null,
                null, null, null, null);
  return cursor;
}
```

Please tell me where is my incorrect. Appreciate.

Comment: What's the value of cursor.getCount()  ?

Comment: @Anirudh I don't understand. Could you please explain for me?

Comment: Can you put this statement in your code - Log.d("TAG","Retrieved rows - " + cursor.getCount()); and tell me what value do you see? Thats the numbers of rows the cursor has retrieved. Do it before return cursor in queueAll() method.

Comment: @Anirudh If I do it before queueAll(), it will get NullPointerException. If I do it after cursor = fileSQLiteAdapter.queueAll();, it will get 0.

Comment: Try this....  http://androidtipsbynama.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-sqlite-database.html

Answer (score 92, accepted):

try:

```
Cursor  cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from table",null);
```

AND  for `List<String>`:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
  while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(countyname));

    list.add(name);
    cursor.moveToNext();
  }
}
```

Comment: I would use this solution myself if needed. However, I am doing `while (!cursor.isAfterLast())`

Comment: or: DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(readableDB.rawQuery("select * from table",null))

Answer (score 6):

### Using Android's built in method

If you want every column and every row, then just pass in `null` for the [`SQLiteDatabase`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase) `column` and `selection` parameters.

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

### More details

The other answers use `rawQuery`, but you can use Android's built in [`SQLiteDatabase`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase). The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) for `query` says that you can just pass in `null` to the `selection` parameter to get all the rows.

> `selection` Passing null will return all rows for the given table.

And while you can also pass in `null` for the `column` parameter to get all of the columns (as in the one-liner above), it is better to only return the columns that you need. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) says

> `columns`  Passing null will return all columns, which is discouraged to prevent reading data from storage that isn't going to be used.

**Example**

```
SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
String[] columns = {
        MyDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_1,
        MyDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_2,
        MyDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_3};
String selection = null; // this will select all rows
Cursor cursor = db.query(MyDatabaseHelper.MY_TABLE, columns, selection,
        null, null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is almost the same solution as the others, but I thought it might be good to look at different ways of achieving the same result and explain a little bit:

Probably you have the table name String variable initialized at the time you called the DBHandler so it would be something like;

```
private static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "anyTableName";
```

Then, wherever you are trying to retrieve all table rows;

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + MYDATABASE_TABLE, null);

List<String> fileName = new ArrayList<>();
if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
   fileName.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME)));
   while(cursor.moveToNext()){
      fileName.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME)));
   }
}
cursor.close();
db.close();
```

Honestly, there are many ways about doing this,

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking into the same problem! I think your problem is related to where you identify the variable that you use to populate the ArrayList that you return. If you define it inside the loop, then it will always reference the last row in the table in the database. In order to avoid this, you have to identify it outside the loop:

```
String name;
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
            name = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(countyname));

            list.add(name);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
}
```

Comment: How does this make your answer any different or more helpful?

Answer (score 1):

**Update `queueAll()` method as below:**

```
public Cursor queueAll() {

     String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + MYDATABASE_TABLE;
     Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

     return cursor;
}
```

**Update `readFileFromSQLite()` method as below:**

```
public ArrayList<String> readFileFromSQLite() {

    fileName = new ArrayList<String>();

    fileSQLiteAdapter = new FileSQLiteAdapter(FileChooser.this);
    fileSQLiteAdapter.openToRead();

    cursor = fileSQLiteAdapter.queueAll();

    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do 
            {
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FileSQLiteAdapter.KEY_CONTENT1));
                fileName.add(name);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

    fileSQLiteAdapter.close();

    return fileName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Cursor cursor = myDb.viewData();

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
              do {
                 String itemname=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDb.col_2));
                 String price=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDb.col_3));
                 String quantity=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDb.col_4));
                 String table_no=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(myDb.col_5));

                 }while (cursor.moveToNext());

                }

                cursor.requery();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<String> getAllData(String email)
{

    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] projection={email};

    List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, //Table to query
            null,    //columns to return
            "user_email=?",        //columns for the WHERE clause
            projection,        //The values for the WHERE clause
            null,       //group the rows
            null,       //filter by row groups
            null);
    //  cursor.moveToFirst();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            list.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("user_id")));
            list.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("user_name")));
            list.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("user_email")));
            list.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("user_password")));
            // cursor.moveToNext();

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to posting on Stack Overflow. Please try to add explanations to the answers. Tips & Improvements: Make sure the cursor is not null, close() the cursor in a finally block and just write while(cursor.moveToNext()) {...},  if-do-while is unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

a concise solution can be used for accessing the cursor rows.

```
while(cursor.isAfterLast)
{
    cursor.getString(0)
    cursor.getString(1)
}
```

These records can be manipulated with a loop

Comment: This will crash the app.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).