# Populate Listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am trying to understand the populating of a list view from data held in a SQLite table. I am using the following code. I have looked at a lot of similar questions on this site but have not been able to figure our where I have gone wrong as there seems to be a myriad of ways to tackle this. This is my bdhandler code:

```
public Product getAllRows(){
    String query = "select * from "+TABLE_PRODUCTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    Product product = new Product();

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            cursor.close();
        }else{
        product = null;
        }
        db.close();
        return product;
}
```

In the activity class, I do not understand what I should be using to populate the list view.

Where can I get more detailed info to try and understand where I am missing what I need to do?

Comment: Is product List of any data? Also share product class and data required form product table.

Comment: Your code says you return only a product new object.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111166/get-all-rows-from-sqlite

Comment: see [this](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter) (Example 4)